# Why do comments with more votes float to the top?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, comments

The comments with more votes appear above comments with less or no votes. I've found that this makes it rather hard to reconstruct a "conversation" had in the comments (esp. when the top comments with votes is referencing another comment).

I know it's been like this for a while, but why?

Is there a way to show comments in the order that they were made?

Comment: No, they do not. Comments do get reduced to show just those with more votes to reduce the length of the comments list. You click on 'show more comments' to expand that list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Click "add/show X more comments" below the top 5 displayed on the post, and you'll see all of the comments posted in chronological order.

The conversations might still not always make sense since comments are sometimes deleted, but usually it works out alright.

Comment: Thank you. Clearly I should have realized this.